# Cannot Connect to Network checked /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: networking, server, internet, dns

I am trying to connect to the network on a ubuntu server 14.04 on a laptop. Pinging to google.com gives unknown host google.com
pinging to 8.8.8.8 gives Network is unreachable

/etc/network/interfaces

```
#The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I can't connect to internet to get the network-manager.
I tried restarting the computer and i tried giving it a static ip both didnt work